# Is this kind of behavior defined by standard?

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char buf[500];
  read(0, buf, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

The above `read` 5 characters from `stdin`,but if I input more than `5`:

```
12345morethan5
[root@ test]# morethan5
-bash: morethan5: command not found
```

The remaining characters will be executed as shell commands.

Is this kind of behavior defined by standard?

Comment: You may find section 3.3.2 of this an interesting read http://www.aosabook.org/en/bash.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of :-)

Your program reads 5 characters, and that's it. Not less, not more. The rest remain in the terminal buffer and get sent to your shell once your C program terminates.

Since you are using `read()`, which is a raw system call, instead of any of the C stdio buffering alternatives this behaviour is not just expected, but *required*.

From the POSIX standard on [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html):

> The read() function shall attempt to
>   read nbyte bytes from the file
>   associated with the open file
>   descriptor, fildes, into the buffer
>   pointed to by buf.
>
> ...
>
> Upon successful completion, where
>   nbyte is greater than 0, read() shall
>   mark for update the st_atime field of
>   the file, and shall return the number
>   of bytes read. **This number shall never
>   be greater than nbyte.**
>
> ...
>
> Upon successful completion, read()
>   [XSI] [Option Start]  and pread()
>   [Option End] shall return a
>   non-negative integer indicating the
>   number of bytes **actually** read.

I.e. `read()` should *never* read more bytes from the file descriptor than requested.

From the [related part](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_06) on terminals:

> It is not, however, necessary to read
>   a whole line at once; any number of
>   bytes, even one, may be requested in a
>   read() **without losing information.**
>
> ...
>
> The **last** process to close a terminal device file shall cause any output to be sent to the device and any input to be discarded.

Note: normally your shell will still have an open file descriptor for the terminal, until you end the session.

Comment: any reference to say that this is **required**?

Comment: @Je Rog: if it is required, I think it will be in the Posix specification of how terminals work. That is, what happens to keypresses that occur while there's a program taking input from the terminal, but aren't read by that program. The specification of the I/O will at most define that the input isn't buffered, and hence that the program indeed doesn't read those chars.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, @Je Rog: there you go :-)

Comment: The quoted text doesn't mention about `The rest should get sent to your shell once your C program terminates.`

Comment: @Je Rog: what else do you think "without losing information" means? It means that the rest of the line is still there to be read from the terminal. In your case the shell is the next thing to read from the terminal after the program exits. Of course the terminal interface doesn't say anything about "C programs" - for all it knows your program is written in Fortran, and for that matter it could have been run directly by `login`, not from a shell.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with any standard, it's up to your runtime what to write to stdin. Your runtime makes the standard input available to your program, which reads some bytes from it and quits, and then the remaining bytes are processed by the runtime itself -- if you can configure it to clear all the file descriptors after forking a process, you could maybe prevent this behaviour, but that would seriously impede most of the standard command line workflows which rely on attaching one process's input to another process's output...

Comment: In this case, there is a relevant standard: the POSIX spec for (pseudo)terminals, and/or the X/Open spec for shell behavior.